# offsetHeight, clientHeight and scrollHeight or offsetWidth, clientWidth and scrollWidth return wrong value for Mackbook retina display

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get retina display document size through JavaScript code

```js
var size = {
    width: Math.max(
        document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        document.body.scrollWidth,
        document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
        document.body.offsetWidth,
        document.documentElement.offsetWidth
    ),
    height: Math.max(
        document.documentElement.clientHeight,
        document.body.scrollHeight,
        document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        document.body.offsetHeight,
        document.documentElement.offsetHeight
    )
};
```

but it will give only half image size in retina display, its working fine on other display
any suggestion how to get clientWidth ,scrollWidth etc for retina display through javascript

Comment: Are you sure you do understand what these values are? They are in CSS `px`, so retina or not that shouldn't change much. Can you please set up a [live example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) so we can check what you are doing exactly?

Comment: okay tell me only one thing how can we get a dynamic size of a webpage in mac book retina display

Comment: What does "dynamic size" mean? Just show us, in an [edit] to your question, what you are doing, what you were expecting and what you got instead.

Answer (score 0):

Retina sets devicePixelRatio to 2 if you multiply your heights and widths by this parameter (which is in most cases 1), you get your proper value.